# What's the direction of gradient vector in this situation?

Tags: temperature, vectors

Recently I came up with the grad vector in electrodynamics course where I read that it is a vector pointing in the direction of the maximum rate of change of the scalar field. This implies that given a scalar field there can be only one such possible vector at each point (right ?).

Now let us consider a temperature field. At a point (say $A(x,y,z)$) the temperature is T. Now at a distance of $dr$ from the point, let the temperature be such that two points on that sphere have same temperature and rest all the points have lesser temperature than that.

[image]
(Let us assume that $T$ is lesser than the temperature at all the points on the sphere).

**Now if I want to find the grad vector then in which direction will it point ?** Or is this kind of distribution not possible ?

Comment: It will depend on the rest of the temperature distribution actually, you can think of any number of functions that satisfy those conditions that yield unique gradients at A.

Comment: How is it a homework based question ?

Answer (score 1):

The function you've described is discontinuous, so it wouldn't be a good model for a physical temperature and it's not differentiable, so we can't really speak of its gradient. But you can modify it: for example, each of the $T_1$ points could have a small bump around it where the temperature rises continuously.

And in that case... it depends. The gradient is a vector of derivatives, $\nabla T = (\partial T / \partial x, \partial T / \partial y, \partial T / \partial z)$, so to calculate it you need to know the function more precisely - you need to be able to take derivatives. In your example, you could fill in the circle in many different ways, so it's not possible to say in which direction the gradient will point.